# eval() Method Returning Undesired Complex Number in Python

Tags: python, math

I am writing some simple mathematical functions in Python. I need to use the eval() method to evaluate a user inputted function. If the user inputs the function y=x**0.4, however, my code starts yielding complex numbers when x is negative. Just as a test, I wrote:

```
print(eval("(-9.451)**0.4"))
```

Where -9.451 is just a random negative number.

This returns:

```
(0.7588806326318368+2.335594429732145j)
```

In reality, (-9.451)**0.4 should evaluate to 2.455789314.

To prove this, observe the graph of y=x**0.4:

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihqhk.jpg)

Why am I getting complex numbers?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In reality, (-9.451)**0.4 should evaluate to 2.455789314

No, the square of the real fifth root of -9.451 is (roughly) 2.455789314. When you use negative numbers as the base of exponents, you lose nice properties like square(fifthroot(x)) = x^0.4. Also, when you use binary floating point, 2/5 isn't exactly representable. The float `0.4` is actually equal to

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(0.4)
Decimal('0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625')
```

... that giant thing, which is the closest representable number to 0.4.

For an operation like `(-9.451)**0.4`, there isn't really a sensible way to interpret it without complex numbers, and it turns out that the best interpretation in terms of complex numbers gives `(0.7588806326318368+2.335594429732145j)`. Python 2 will give you an error instead of doing complex arithmetic:

```
>>> (-9.451)**0.4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power
```

The graph you linked looks like a bug in the tool you used. It should either not show anything for x < 0 or show something like what [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E0.4) shows, with a nonzero imaginary part for x < 0.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response. I shall try to keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you realize that you are trying to compute the root of a negative number? You could just use the `abs` function here to solve this problem, I guess :)

```
>>> eval("abs(-9.451)**0.4")
2.4557893140046687
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I suppose I was just getting confused because my graphing calculator tells me that -9.451 raised to the 0.4 is 2.456. I don't know why that is, but I completely understand that the root of a negative number cannot be taken. I will use your solution....it more than solves my problem. Thanks again for your help, and sorry for my not thinking it through as well as I should have!

Answer (score 0):

No, 0.7588806326318368+2.335594429732145j is the correct answer.

2.455789314 would be the result of 9.451**0.4, not -9.451.

Comment: But if you look at the graph of y=x^0.4, it's clear that both positive 9.451 and negative 9.451 should evaluate to 2.456. Try it in Desmos (https://www.desmos.com/calculator)

Comment: @Eragon20: I don't know what that thing is doing, but it looks wrong. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E0.4) gives complex numbers.

Comment: @Eragon20 Desmos gives 'undefined' for the square root of -1: it is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was getting confused because of the graph Desmos was giving me. Thank you so much for correcting me!